# C# - Dapper/MySql - How to run a query with user-defined variable

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I've been trying to run this code:

```
using System;
using Dapper;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace DapperTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new MySqlConnection(@"mysql_connstr_here"))
            {
                var sql = @"
                    set @foo := (select count(*) from table1);
                    select table2.*, @foo from table2;";
                var result = db.Query(sql);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Reader.set(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader)
```

My first guess is that the variable is being treated as a SqlParameter, and since I'm not passing any argument to it, my code fails.
Is there a way to run a query like that using Dapper?

Comment: It's probably bugging out because the column has no name. Perhaps just use `db.ExecuteScalar(sql)` as there is only one column in the `SELECT`

Comment: There are more efficient ways of setting an integer to 0 in c#. Can you make the example less contrived/post a query that is *reasonable*? As is I'd vote to close it as a typo because the code is of very little practical use to anyone

Comment: @CaiusJard I've just edited the example to more clear on what I want to accomplish, although the previous one ran in the same exception. I need count the  registers in table1 and return it as a column in the query of table2. I have some constraints due the version of the MySql server I'm using, so my query have to be like that. The query runs as expected, but when I try to run it in C#, I get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this in [the Dapper documentation](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper#user-defined-variables-in-mysql):

> In order to use Non-parameter SQL variables with MySql Connector, you have to add the following option to your connection string:
>
> Allow User Variables=True
>
> Make sure you don't provide Dapper with a property to map.

So all I needed to do was to `Allow User Variables=True` to the connection string. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The NullReferenceException you are receiving is likely because you have not defined foo as a parameter.

```
  using (var db = new MySqlConnection(@"mysql_connstr_here"))
  {
    var sql = dbConnection.QueryFirstOrDefault<int>(
      @" 
      select @foo;",
      new
      {
        foo = userAssignedVariable
      });
  }
```

Comment: In my case, @foo is not supposed to be a parameter. It's a user defined variable that is going to be set within the SQL statement, and then returned alongside some other data in the select.

Comment: I've updated my answer to assist with that. Set @foo with the user assigned variable as a new parameter. This will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can else write your sql with a valid sql variable declaration :

`var sql = @"declare @foo int = 0; select @foo;";`

*Note : tested with Sql Server, not MySql. I don't use it.*